# macOS Server App no longer saves Websites settings

Tags: osx-server, server.app

I have configured about a dozen virtual sites in the Server app under Websites. It suddenly occurred that when I edit one of these websites (no matter what I edit), I click on *Save* and nothing happens. In the end, I have to click *Cancel*, and when I check back, indeed my changes have not been saved.

Any idea why this is so and how to fix this?

I've checked the access rights in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites`, but they seem okay. Restarts didn't cure it either.

I'm running Server app 5.3.1 under macOS Sierra 10.12.6. The sites run fine.

Answer (score 1):

First you should enable debug mode in Server.app by running the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.ServerFoundation DebugModeEnabled YES
```

and restarting Server.app. This should enable the debug menu. Then make sure the "Log Actions To Server Log" item is checked. Rerun your test, and then look at the log file in ~/Library/Logs/Server.log. The file shows the request/response communications between the Server.app and the backend admin tools. Look for commands to servermgr_web, most commands are in plist format, though the web commands may be in a JSON format.

Look for writeSettings commands specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the log, I get `Error from action: <0x3A7540> Writing Websites settings` with `<key>error</key>
 <string>Error Domain=XSServerFoundationErrorDomain Code=7 "Failed to write settings." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to write settings.}</string>`, but now I don't know how to proceed? Where can I lookup `Code=7`?

Comment: Okay, searching the web for this error message did not exactly result in an explanation, but I found that several people got this problem in context with SSL certificates. So I went through my SSL websites entries and found one that would not save. I deleted and recreated it, and after that, editing and saving of my other websites worked again.